# Red exclamation mark when trying to update Nexus 7.

Tags: updates, nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean

Every time I go to update my Google Nexus 7 to Android Jelly Bean 4.2, it fails and shows the Android logo on it's side with red exclamation mark (!) on.

Why won't it let me update to Jelly Bean 4.2?

Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: How much free space do you have on your device?

Comment: I have over 23gb free of a 32gb model

Comment: Any idea on what the problem is?!

Comment: Am I the only one having this issue with updating the Nexus 7 Jelly Bean to 4.2.1?

Comment: Any other salient details? Is it rooted? Have you flashed a custom ROM? What country are you in? Does it have 3G? (Please add this information to your question.)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I manually (via titanium backup) uninstalled one of the system apps: the korean keyboard (which, for me, is rather pointless). Somehow that caused the upgrading process to fail, maybe because my system was not "intact". After I restored the app it worked flawlessly. Did you make any modifications like that? If so, try reverting them.